# my xcode organizer is disabled and all organizer are grey can NOT choose them

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

this happens after an error that appears in organizer several time when running the program in Xcode.
the error is Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC011).

any help to  guide me  get rid of this problem this is highly appreciated

[image: This photo does not add much but this what i got in all xcode files !]

Comment: It's impossible to help without any more information. And even then, this looks like a bug in Xcode, so the best thing you could do is gather as much data and information as you can, and submit a [bug report](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbugreporter.apple.com%2F&ei=LqOSUdO9PMqV7AbKwoDADQ&usg=AFQjCNFp0WKoyPDnMBW-fA9zohPsgOwByg&sig2=kRBUaU0Y4eCLBWSaYX0TzA&bvm=bv.46471029,d.ZGU).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: does anybody have idea on how to go around this bug

Comment: I suggest you reinstall your xcode. Some of the foundation files are corrupted. The best way is to reinstall the xcode.

Comment: actually i just restarted my computer and the organizer is working BUT the error is appearing again which is: Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC011) ‘file exists/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-2083/DTDeviceKit/DTDKApplication.m:1474

Answer (score 1):

Even when its too late but maybe for somebody else. The problem is either in your computer nor in your xcode. You must check the way you are saving the data in the files ( saving from two resource at the same file).  `error (0xC011)` is for logging data in files.
Check your code, then delete the app. from your device then start it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my computer and the organizer is working now, However,the error is appearing again that is:

> Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC011) ‘file
>   exists/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-2083/DTDeviceKit/DTDKApplication.m:14‌​74